# Excel VBA: Receiving Method 'Union' of object'_Applcation' failed when macro loops

Tags: vba, excel

I keep getting a 'union of object'_application' error when a macro needs to loop to other rows of a filtered range. The macro takes data from a row in a filtered range on workbook1, opens a second workbook2 and places the data in various locations. While the second workbook2 is open, I need to copy/paste some existing data within workbook2 based on a value placed by workbook1. Workbook2 is saved-as and closed and a loop continues to the next row of the filtered range in workbook1 and keeps going until the next cell isEmpty. This macro seems to work fine if my filtered range contains only 1 row and doesn't need to loop. Any more than that and I get the error. I am a noob so I'm guessing my macro is very sloppy. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Public Sub CreateAllPullTickets()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim project As String
Dim cablenumber As String
Dim rev As Single
Dim tolocation As String
Dim fromlocation As String
Dim cabletype As String
Dim todwg As String
Dim fromdwg As String
Dim p1pulltemplate As Workbook
Dim r As Range
Dim StartRow As Long
Dim filteredNum As String
Dim cablenumberPT As String
Dim rCell1 As Range
Dim rRng1 As Range
Dim rCell2 As Range
Dim rRng2 As Range
Dim targetRange1 As Range
Dim targetRange2 As Range

On Error GoTo Errorcatch

Set r = ActiveSheet.Range("A3:A80000").Rows.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
StartRow = r.Row
filteredNum = Worksheets("MasterCableSchedule").Range("A1")

If ActiveCell.Column <> 1 Or ActiveCell.Row <> StartRow Then
MsgBox ("Please Select First Cable In Column A")
Else
MSG2 = MsgBox("Create " & filteredNum & " Pull Tickets?", vbYesNo)
If MSG2 = vbYes Then
    Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
        Worksheets("MasterCableSchedule").Select
        project = Range("G1")
        cablenumber = Range(ActiveCell.Address)
        rev = Range(ActiveCell.Address).Offset(0, 1)
        fromlocation = Range(ActiveCell.Address).Offset(0, 2)
        tolocation = Range(ActiveCell.Address).Offset(0, 4)
        cabletype = Range(ActiveCell.Address).Offset(0, 6)
        todwg = Range(ActiveCell.Address).Offset(0, 5)
        fromdwg = Range(ActiveCell.Address).Offset(0, 3)

        Set p1pulltemplate = Workbooks.Open("C:\TEST\WORKBOOK2.xlsm")

        Worksheets("CablePullTicket").Select
        With Worksheets("CablePullTicket")
        Worksheets("CablePullTicket").Range("E2") = project
        Worksheets("CablePullTicket").Range("E4") = cablenumber
        Worksheets("CablePullTicket").Range("E5") = rev
        Worksheets("CablePullTicket").Range("E6") = tolocation
        Worksheets("CablePullTicket").Range("R6") = fromlocation
        Worksheets("CablePullTicket").Range("E7") = cabletype
        Worksheets("CablePullTicket").Range("E8") = todwg
        Worksheets("CablePullTicket").Range("R8") = fromdwg
        End With

        cablenumberPT = Worksheets("CablePullTicket").Range("E4")
        Set targetRange1 = Worksheets("LabeLImport").Cells(1, 2)
        Set targetRange2 = Worksheets("LabeLImport").Cells(2, 2)

        'IF LOOP NEEDS TO CONTINUE, I BELIEVE THIS IS WHERE IT ERRORS

        For Each rCell1 In Worksheets("PointsList").Range("B1:B30000")
                If rCell1.Value = cablenumberPT Then
                    If rRng1 Is Nothing Then
                        Set rRng1 = rCell1.Offset(0, 6)
                    Else
                        Set rRng1 = Application.Union(rRng1,            rCell1.Offset(0, 6))
                    End If
                End If
        Next
        rRng1.Copy
        targetRange1.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, operation:=xlNone,    skipblanks:=False, Transpose:=True

        Application.CutCopyMode = False

        For Each rCell2 In Worksheets("PointsList").Range("B1:B30000")
                If rCell2.Value = cablenumberPT Then
                    If rRng2 Is Nothing Then
                        Set rRng2 = rCell2.Offset(0, 7)
                    Else
                        Set rRng2 = Application.Union(rRng2, rCell2.Offset(0, 7))
                    End If
                End If
        Next
        rRng2.Copy
        targetRange2.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, operation:=xlNone, skipblanks:=False, Transpose:=True

        Application.CutCopyMode = False

        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\TEST\Pull Tickets\" & fromlocation & " - #" & cablenumber & ".xlsm", _
                                FileFormat:=(52), _
                                CreateBackup:=False
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False

        Do
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        Loop While ActiveCell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Loop
Else
End If
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Exit Sub

Errorcatch:
MsgBox Err.Description

End Sub
```

Comment: have you actually stepped through the code line-by-line to see exactly where it errors and why? that will tell a lot. Also, from a quick glance, it seems that `rRng1` would never be nothing after the first loop, because you never clear it out after you are done the loop. Also, stay away from .`ActiveCell` and `.Select`. it's cancerous to your code and produces errors often. Instead work directly with the specific cells you need.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Setting rRng1 & 2 to nothing before the next loop began was the fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that you need to set `rRng1` and `rRng2` to `Nothing` before the For Each loop.

```
Set rRng1 = Nothing
For Each rCell1 in ...
```

That error means that you're trying to `Union` two ranges that can't be unioned  - most commonly, two cells that are on different worksheets. Your situation is a little more subtle than that. On some level, the cells you're trying to combine are on the same sheet. The problem is that you're opening `PointsList` each time you loop. So while you always look at the same sheet on `PointsList`, Excel thinks of it as completely different workbook.  Take this example:

```
Sub test()

    Dim r As Range
    Dim rCell As Range

    Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\dkusleika\Dropbox\Excel\Workbook2.xlsm"

    Set r = Range("a1")

    ActiveWorkbook.Close

    Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\dkusleika\Dropbox\Excel\Workbook2.xlsm"

    Set r = Application.Union(Range("a2"), r)

    ActiveWorkbook.Close

End Sub
```

All this does is try to union `A1` and `A2`on the active sheet of `Workbook2.xlsm`. But since I close and reopen the workbook, I get the same error as you. Excel just can't seem to reconcile that they're the same.

In your case, `rRng1` still contains the range from the previous loop when it tries to add more ranges from the newly opened `PointsList`. Not only is that causing the error, I don't think it's what you want. I think you want rRng1 to be different for each iteration of the loop with no carryover from the previous iteration. Setting it `Nothing` before you loop through the range will do that.

Comment: nailed it. Yes, rRng1 & 2 are different through every loop. Setting them to nothing was the fix.